# Javascript two-way reference issue

Tags: javascript, reference

I am very confused about Javascript referencing. I understand when referencing an object, there is a reference made. Changing the parent changes the copy and vice versa.

What I am confused about is when reassignment changes are made to the parent, the copy retains everything. See my example

```
let tester = {
  "hello": "how are you",
  "myArrayHere": [
    { "id": 1, "name": "me" },
    { "id": 2, "name": "you" },
    { "id": 3, "name": "them" },
  ]
};

var something = tester.myArrayHere.find(x => x.name === "you");

console.log(something);
console.log("--------");

something.id = 99;
console.log(something);
console.log("--------");

console.log(tester.myArrayHere[1]);
console.log("--------");

tester.myArrayHere[1].id = 88;

console.log(something);
console.log("--------");

tester.myArrayHere[1] = {};
console.log(tester.myArrayHere[1]);
console.log("--------");

console.log(something)
```

If you run that example, `something` on the last line, still has the entire object, even though two lines above, its reference was re-assigned.

There are other examples of this, such as when you delete things off the parent, etc. If this is purely a reference and not a copy (such as with primitive types) why are these changes not affecting it as it should?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `something` variable simply refers to a (pre-defined) object stored in the memory. It's value is the returned value (a *referral* to an object) of the `Array#find` method. Variables do not observe any specific path (e.g. `tester.myArrayHere[1]`), they are not *observers*. In other words, in this case, JavaScript interpreter doesn't care/remember *how* you get the object/value before the assignment.

```
> var a, b; a = b = {};
> a === b
true
> a = {}
> a === b
false
```

After executing `tester.myArrayHere[1] = {};`, the second element of the array **refers** to *a new object*. The `something` variable still **refers** to *the old object*.

Answer (score 1):

Please check the explanation in a snippet

```js
let tester = { // tester is a link to a object (not an object itself) in memory
  "hello": "how are you",
  "myArrayHere": [ // tester.myArrayHere is a link to a object (not an object itself) in memory
    { "id": 1, "name": "me" },
    { "id": 2, "name": "you" }, // tester.myArrayHere[1] is a link to a object (not an object itself) in memory
    { "id": 3, "name": "them" },
  ]
};

var something = tester.myArrayHere.find(x => x.name === "you"); // something now is the same link to the object { "id": 2, "name": "you" }, but not an object itself tester.myArrayHere[1] will be === something link is eqaul to link

console.log(something);
console.log("--------");

something.id = 99;
console.log(something);
console.log("--------");

console.log(tester.myArrayHere[1]);
console.log("--------");

tester.myArrayHere[1].id = 88;

console.log(something);
console.log("--------");

tester.myArrayHere[1] = {}; // now tester.myArrayHere[1] becomes a link to a new object, { "id": 2, "name": "you" } is still in a memory and something is link to it
console.log(tester.myArrayHere[1]);
console.log("--------");

console.log(something)
```

Answer (score 0):

Its best to conceptualize the code you posted as "having a direct shortcut to the nested field"

```js
const joe = {    // (A) joe is an object
  id: 42,
  name: 'joe',
  hobbies: [     // (B) hobbies is an Array, a reference type
    'surfing',
    'videogames'
  ]
}

// (C) this variable has no idea that it is part of person object from (A)
const cloneHobbies = joe.hobbies
cloneHobbies.push('boxing') 

console.log('***JOE***', joe) // Joe now has a new hobby: boxing

// It also works the other way; Joe's hobbies become someone else's 
joe.hobbies.push('karate')

console.log("***CLONE'S HOBBIES***", cloneHobbies) // now has 'karate'
```

Hope this helps you conceptualize the code.
Cheers,